# Scroll two Swiper Slider Slideshows at the same time

Tags: jquery, swiper.js

I have two swiper slideshows which should scroll simultaneously. It's working so far. But I want to invert the scrolling direction of the second Slideshow and keep the natural direction of the first. I tried to achieve this making the negative translate value positive. But it's not really working... Here is what I have done so far:

Codepen:
https://codepen.io/Dennisade/pen/eaRLZW

```js
var numItems = $('.swiper-slide').length;

var imageSlider = new Swiper(".image-slider", {
  loopedSlides: numItems,
  loop: true,
  slidesPerView: "auto",
  freeMode: true,
  mousewheel: {
    releaseOnEdges: true,
  }
});

var overlay = new Swiper(".overlay", {
  loopedSlides: numItems,
  loop: true,
  slidesPerView: "auto",
  freeMode: true,
  reverseDirection: true,
  mousewheel: {
    releaseOnEdges: true,
    invert:true,
  },
});

imageSlider.on('setTranslate', function onSliderMove() {
  var scrollValue = this.translate;
  overlay.setTranslate(scrollValue);
});
```

```css
.swiper-container,
.swiper-wrapper {
  height: 50vh;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: end;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.swiper-wrapper {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: end;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.swiper-slide {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: end;
  align-items: flex-end;
  width: auto;
}
.swiper-slide img {
  max-width: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.thumbContainer img {
  display: block;
  max-width: auto;
  width:100%
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.0/css/swiper.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="image-text">Value</div>

<div class="swiper-container image-slider">

  <div class="swiper-wrapper overlay-wrapper">
   
    <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="thumbContainer">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/560/FF0000/FFFFFF?Text=Down.com">
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="thumbContainer">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/560/FF0000/FFFFFF?Text=Down.com">
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="thumbContainer">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/560/FF0000/FFFFFF?Text=Down.com">
        </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>

</div>


<div class="swiper-container overlay">

  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
   
    <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="thumbContainer">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/560/000000/FFFFFF?Text=Down.com">
        </div>
    </div>
    
     <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="thumbContainer">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/560/000000/FFFFFF?Text=Down.com">
        </div>
    </div>
    
     <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="thumbContainer">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/560/000000/FFFFFF?Text=Down.com">
        </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>

</div>






<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.0/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why not two images in a single slide?

Comment: The images will be different. The idea is to have both image slideshow above of each other. One Slideshow should scroll from left to right  and the other one from right to left

Answer (score 4):

You can use `slidesPerGroup` property to group multiple slides, which allows you to scroll multiple slides at once.
To understand it deeper, and how you can customise it, please see the API documentation here [Swiper Api](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#parameters)